# Windows scripting: list files not matching a pattern

Tags: regex, windows, pattern-matching

In Windows 7 command prompt, I´d like to list all files of a folder which name does not start with `abc`. I have tried:

```
forfiles /P C:\myFolder\ /M ^[abc]* /S /C "CMD /C echo @file"
```

Where is my error?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at `forfiles /?`:

> ```
> /M    searchmask    Searches files according to a searchmask.
>                     The default searchmask is '*' .
> ```

which strongly suggests `forfiles` doesn't support regular expressions, just normal Cmd/Windows wildcards.

On Windows 7 this can easily be achieved in PowerShell:

```
dir c:\myFolder | ?{ -not($_.Name -match '^abc') } | select Name
```

(That performs a case-*in*sensitive regular expression match, which doesn't matter in the case of Windows filenames.)

NB. Assuming you want files not starting `ABC`, which isn't what your (attempted) regular expression says (any filename starting something that isn't `a`, `b` or `c`).

Answer (score 1):

> Where is my error?

Your error is thinking that the `forfiles` command would support regular expressions.

It does not. It supports file name matching with `*` and `?`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, in case of using a `xcopy` command instead of `echo` is using the option `/exclude`. For instance:

```
forfiles /P C:\myFolder\ /M ^[abc]* /S /C "CMD /C xcopy @path %myDestinationFolder% /exclude:abc*"
```

Also, if you´re using PowerShell, another option is the operator `-match`.