# How do I find a string in text files and print the matches in a Windows batch file?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Is there a way to search for a defined string within several thousand text files and to print the names of the files that have a match?

Comment: this is not batch but you can try the 'find in files' menu in notepad++ this works great

Answer (score 3):

```
findstr /M "searched string" *.txt > matchingFiles.out
```

From `findstr /?` documentation:

```
/M         Prints only the filename if a file contains a match.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which OS platform to be answered for,

But Linux/Unix systems can have the following command used for this purpose.

```
find . -name '*.ext' -type f | xargs fgrep 'pattern to be searched'
```

This will search the files starting from current directory and check for the 'pattern to be searched'. The file name pattern with wildcard can be applied where I have used '*.ext'

Comment: Oh sorry, I truely forgot to mention my OS.
It is Windows 7 :/

But thank you for your answer anyway :)

Comment: Ok. A powershell option slightly just the opposite is mentioned in the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440692/windows-scripting-list-files-not-matching-a-pattern